# RegEx for e-mail address outside code comment

Tags: javascript, regex

Using RegEx, I am trying to match any e-mail address outside of a code comment.

For example, the string could be something like this:

```
/**
 * Hello World
 * For comment info e-mail us at test@email.com
 */
But we really want to match this@email.com
```

So in this case, I would only want to return 'this@email.com'. What RegEx formula could I use in this case?

Comment: Just matching an email address at all takes a complicated regex (unless you deliberately ignore more obscure but theoretically valid address formats). Do you already have an expression that matches emails in a general sense?

Comment: to match commented text use reg expression.                                             /((?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:\/\/.*))/ .try to get content which is not matched with this reg expr and then check for any email id in that content.hope this will help you.

Comment: @Murali: That won't compile

Comment: /[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+/ will match the first e-mail address, but I want the e-mail address outside of code comments.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are often seen as some *magic language* that will do anything we need with a text string if only we knew the incantation. It's not like that, and you shouldn't let your progammer-sense be subverted by the idea. Your core language should do the heavy lifting, leaving regex patterns to do the detailed work

It's unclear whether you need a Perl solution or a JavaScript one, or if you're equivocal. This is for Perl

How to *"match any e-mail address outside of a code comment"*?

- Remove the comments

  This is addressed in [perlfaq6](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file%3f)
- Search for email addresses

  You should use the
  [`Regexp::Common`](http://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Common) module, together with
  [`Regexp::Common::Email::Address`](http://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Common::Email::Address).
  But beware that this will match anything defined by the [*Internet Message Format* standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), which may be rather more than you imagine an "email address" to be. It's a lot more than just `bob@example.com`

  See also
  [`Email::Address`](http://metacpan.org/module/Email::Address)
  if you need to process any email addresses that you find

Comment: Worth a +1 for the 'not every job is for regex' alone.